# Check my private key from created ssh keys

Tags: ssh

I use ssh-keygen -t rsa to generate ssh keys, I learned that my private key is saved to the id_rsa file in the .ssh directory, I wonder what mac ox command line that I should use to see what my private keys is?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

or

```
open ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Works the same for id_rsa.pub